# TFS run unit tests failing because of missing files

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, tfsbuild, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a big code base in TFS which has multiple .sln files, each with many projects and at least one unit test project.  Most of the unit tests rely on common XML and XSD files, and there are several other types of files (.config, .xaml, etc) that are needed by the code when unit testing.

Because of the way that TFS builds and gathers the files for unit testing, most of those files are missing from the TestResults folder, so the tests are failing during our CI builds [this has been happening for a while, but I'm new to the project, and am trying to fix the errors].  What TFS appears to do is this:  First, it checks out all the code to a src folder (with Solution1, Solution2, etc) and builds it, just like the developers do locally.  Second, it copies the build outputs to a bin\Binaries folder.  Third, it looks for all the *test*.dll files, copies them and their dependencies (but only the dependencies), plus the App.config file to TestResults\Deploy_[date/time]\Out folder, and runs the unit tests there.

I am encountering two problems with this.  Because the second step is combining all the build outputs into one folder, all the files with duplicate names are overwriting each other.  So, there is only one App.config file, even though each solution has its own.  This is happening with other config/xml files too, and with two poorly named unit test .dlls.  I can live with this if I have to because most of those config files are duplicates, and other files can be renamed.

The second problem is that most of those extra files don't make it into the TestResults folder, and when they aren't there the unit tests will fail.  I know about using the [DeploymentItem] attribute; if that is the only solution, I will go that route, but there are so many extra files that I am looking for a different approach.

So my question is, how can I configure my tfs-run builds & unit tests to include all of the files that they need, without all the work & maintenance problems of adding a lot of [DeploymentItem] attributes, and also without affecting the local builds & unit tests for the developers?

## Update

One thing I've found is that adding a [DeploymentItem] attribute to a unit test actually causes the deployment folder to be used.  Without that, it runs the unit tests in the binaries folder.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx, under "When is a separate deployment folder used?"

Also on that page, it says you can specify files to deploy in a .testsettings file, but then says you should avoid using it because your tests will run slower.  The newer alternative, a .runsettings file, does not let you list what files to deploy.

It also appears that deployment becomes enabled if code coverage is enabled, which we don't currently do, but plan to once the tests are passing.

Comment: You should search for "unit test deployment". These files need to be deployed. It has nothing to do with TFS builds, per se.

Comment: I've hit a similar problem where I've got a file in one of my projects (build type "content", "copy always"). Unit tests that require this file work fine on my PC but fail on the TFS (2012) server - I can see that the file has been copied to the server's `\1\[project_name]\[build_name]\bin\ folder`, but it's not in the `\1\[project_name]\[build_name]\tst\[test_name]\Out\` folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: You seem to be saying that unit tests can be configured to run from the \bin folder on the server. I don't have any .testsettings files or [DeploymentItem] attributes, yet my unit test insists on running under this \tst\ folder. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

In TFS 2013 you can execute a powershell pre-test to organize the files in a way that you need. You can get files to be deployed ad part of the tests with a test settings file for pre2013.

If however the test setting file is not enough you can use the Community Build tools to call a powershell directly in previous versions to 2013.

If you are stuck on 2012 then you will need to use the .testsettings file to push the bits you need. Yes it will make your build slower but that's your only choice other than customising the build process as above.

Comment: We're still using TFS 2012.  Any equivalent for that?

Comment: You can use the test setting file as described. However why have you not yet updated to 2013?

Comment: I have no idea why not.  IT doesn't want to support it, management doesn't want to buy it, something else?  It's out of my control.

Comment: And if IT is not keeping software up to date with the latest versions they are incompetent.